# SQL Query to display status as "Not Entered" for employees' timesheets for agiven list of dates

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've been searching online for an answer but no luck. I just created an account & am new here so forgive me if the post is messed up.

I will mention the important tables needed for my query,

I have 3 tables in MS Access (for the time being until we migrate to SQL Server):

- `T_Employee` -> Emp_ID, Emp_name,...
- `T_Custom_Calendar_Dates` -> YearNo, MonthNo, WeekNo, Week_Start_Date, Week_End_Date
- `T_Timesheet_Header` -> Emp_ID, Week_End_Date,...

.

1. The `T_Employee` table will have the list of employees and the Emp_ID as primary key of course
2. The `T_Custom_calendar_Dates` table has the following sample data:

   ```
   Year_No   Month_No      WeekNo     Week_Start_Date    Week_End_Date
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------
   2015           1           1        02/01/2015         08/01/2015
   2015           1           2        09/01/2015         15/01/2015
   2015           1           3        16/01/2015         22/01/2015
   2015           1           4        23/01/2015         29/01/2015
   2015           1           5        30/01/2015         05/02/2015
   2015           2           1        06/02/2015         12/02/2015
   2015           2           2        13/02/2015         19/02/2015
   2015           2           3        20/02/2015         26/02/2015
   2015           2           4        27/02/2015         05/03/2015
   and so on till Month_No reaches 12
   ```
3. The `T_Timesheet_Header` table should have the `EMP_ID` and `Week_End_Date` like this :

   ```
   Emp_ID    Week_End_Date     ,other columns
   ----------------------------------
     1       08/01/2015
     1       15/01/2015
     1       29/01/2015
   ```

Notice I have skipped entering a record for 22/01/2015

so the query I'm looking for is to display something like :

```
Week_End_Date           Emp_ID         Status
08/01/2015                1            Entered
15/01/2015                1            Entered
22/01/2015                1            Not Entered
29/01/2015                1            Entered
08/01/2015                2            Not Entered
15/01/2015                2            Not Entered
22/01/2015                2            Not Entered
29/01/2015                2            Not Entered
```

and so on for the rest of the `Week_end_date` list from the `T_Custom_Calendar_Dates` table.

I'm not sure if it is possible without creating a temp table

I tried fiddling with the SQL joins but no luck, hope some SQL guru comes by and helps me with it

Comment: thanks marc_s for making my post look better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get a combination of distinct `emp_id` and `Week_End_dates` so all combinations are accounted for. You can do this with an `CROSS JOIN`

```
SELECT
    t1.Week_End_Date,
    t2.Emp_ID
FROM
    T_Custom_Calendar_Dates As T1,
        (
            SELECT Emp_ID FROM T_Timesheet_Header GROUP BY Emp_ID
        ) as T2
```

You can use this as subquery to join back to the `T_Timesheet_Header` table to determine if that unique combination of `Week_End_Date`/`EmpID` is present in the `T_Timesheet_Header`

```
SELECT
    T3.Week_End_Date,
    T3.Emp_ID,
    IIF(ISNULL(T4.Emp_ID), "Not Entered", "Entered") AS [Status]
FROM
    (
            SELECT
                t1.Week_End_Date,
                t2.Emp_ID
            FROM
                T_Custom_Calendar_Dates As T1,                  
                (
                    SELECT Emp_ID FROM T_Timesheet_Header GROUP BY Emp_ID
                ) as T2
    ) as T3
    LEFT JOIN T_Timesheet_Header as T4 ON
        T3.Week_End_DAte = T4.Week_End_Date AND
        T3.Emp_ID = T4.Emp_ID
```

Comment: You may not get away with LEFT OUTER JOIN, it depends on the version of MS Access. I was thinking `SELECT DueIn.EmpId, DueIn.Week_End_Date, IIf(IsNull(T_Timesheet_Header.[Week_End_Date]),"Not Entered","Entered") AS [Entered?]
FROM (SELECT T_Custom_calendar_Dates.Week_End_Date, T_Employee.EmpId
FROM T_Custom_calendar_Dates, T_Employee)  AS DueIn LEFT JOIN T_Timesheet_Header ON (DueIn.EmpId = T_Timesheet_Header.Emp_ID) AND (DueIn.Week_End_Date = T_Timesheet_Header.Week_End_Date)
ORDER BY DueIn.EmpId, DueIn.Week_End_Date;` It may need a WHERE to get to before current date.

Comment: It's been a long time since I did any real work in Access, so you may be right. I dropped the `OUTER` bit from the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` since it will work either way.

Comment: thanks JNevill , I tried yours and it worked (a "," was missing before the IIF(ISNULL(T4.Emp_ID), "Not Entered", "Entered") AS [Status]). but the employee table is missing for it to display the result for each employee, because currently it is displaying the same emp_id for all the rows . I will give Fionnuala's reply a try too

Comment: I fixed the comma. To get each employee in there change `SELECT Emp_ID FROM T_Timesheet_Header GROUP BY Emp_ID` to `SELECT EMP_ID FROM T_EMployee`. That way all combinations are present. I should have caught that and didn't.

Comment: I tried both of your queries and they both gave the returned same result which I wanted! I don't know how to thank ya'll ! Now I can continue my work based on the results. I appreciate your efforts guys, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but give it a try

```
select tccd.Week_End_Date, 
  tth.Emp_ID, 
  SWITCH(IsNull(tth.Emp_ID), 'Not Entered',
              TRUE, 'Entered') AS Status
from T_Custom_calendar_Dates tccd left join T_Timesheet_Header tth 
on tccd.Emp_ID = th.Emp_ID
```

Comment: I gave your answer a try but got some error , thanks tho